# Notifications are never shown in emulator

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to show a notification at a certain date and time. I have tried a lot, but it is never showing in the emulator. I found and edited this piece of code:

```
createnotification() {
    let remindid = new Date().getUTCMilliseconds();
    this.date = moment(“2019-01-31 12:20:00”).format(“YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss”);

    let notification = {
        id: remindid,
        title: this.title,
        text: this.description, 
        forceShow: 'true',
        coldstart: true,
        foreground: false,
        at: this.date
    };

    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule(notification);

    let alert = this.alrtCtrl.create({
      title: 'Notifications set at ' + this.date,
      buttons: ['Ok']
    });

    alert.present();
}
```

I think it has something to do with the “at” property. I tried different variations of the date, used the “trigger”-property. Nothing seems to work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

Monthnumbers are zero based, so I was pointing at March.

January = 0

February = 1

March = 2

Etc.